# Is there any way we can pause milestones?

Tags: case, service-cloud-console, casemilestone

I am in a situation where i want to pause the milestone clock until the status of the case does not changes to 'completed'.
The situation is , milestones are triggering on the basis of case status.
And in scenario if user changes status from A to B and then to C that is working fine. But issue is if due to some reason user switch back to status A from C , then the clock starts from zero and not from where it stops earlier and that is affecting the reporting.

So what i am thinking, if there is any way to pause the clock so that if user switch back to status A from C , that clock resume.

Answer (score 4):

When you use Entitlement & Milestones, Case object will have an attribute called `Stopped` (API: `IsStopped`). You can make it as `true` to stop milestone.

You can create workflow or trigger to stop the milestone using,

```
objCase.IsStopped = true;
```

Also, you can calculate how long it is being stopped using `StopStartDate` attribute.

Again, if you change the status clock will start from where you left off.

Comment: Thanks. but issue is if i marked the milestone Stop by using this way, my next milestone will not trigger, because on the success action the status chanes form A to B and that results in triggering of next milestone and so on. 
So the question is , unless milestone does not completed and stopped. How next milestone will start ?

Comment: You sould start milestone based on status changes at your milestone configuration, this type of usecase i have already done in my project

Comment: thanks. But can we pause milestone A [such that clock stops ]and go to B when status change maually, and then go from B to C [pause clock for B as well]. Now from C [when clock for c is running] , if i switch back to status [that take me back to milestone A]. resume the clock for A milestone and pause the clock for milestone C .

I got your point of using isStopped field. But how do i handle which milestone to stop at specifc time. Please help